# Iterate through an array in an object

Tags: c#, loops, iteration

I'm trying to iterate through the array of Grades which is initiated in the students object but get 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object'. I believed the following line `for (int i = 0; i < (students[i].Grades.Length); i++)` only would run three times (size of Grades array) then terminate, but it seems like its aiming to fulfill the iteration of students?:

If so, I'm kind of lost and wonder how to reach the field of the Subject instead of using this kind of iteration? Might add I'm a newbie so any advice is much appreciated!

```
// Iteration problems
        for (int i = 0; i < (students[i].Grades.Length); i++)
        {
            Console.Write(" {0}: ", students[i].Grades[i].Subject);
        }
```

Parts of the code in larger context:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        public Student[] students = new Student[] { };
        students = new Student[5];

// Iteration problems

        for (int i = 0; i < (students[i].Grades.Length); i++)
        {
            Console.Write(" {0}: ", students[i].Grades[i].Subject);
        }
    } 
}
class Student
{
    public GradeSubject[] Grades { get; set; } = new GradeSubject[] 
    {
        new GradeSubject("Art"),
        new GradeSubject("Geography"),
        new GradeSubject("Math"),
    };
}
public class GradeSubject
{
    private string subject;
    private char letter;

    // Properties
    public string Subject { get { return subject; } set { subject = value; } }
    public char Letter { get { return letter; } set { letter = value; } }

    public GradeSubject(string _subject)
    {
        subject = _subject;
    }
}
```

Comment: This answers your question: [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: `students = new Student[5];` assigns a 5-element array of `Student`s to `students` but does not actually create any `Student` instances.  Instead, every element of `students` is `null` until you make it otherwise.  You need to do the same thing you did with `Grades`: assign some instances to its elements.

Comment: One way I learned to fix NullReferenceEx is by stepping through the code with a breakpoint and seeing what is null. then once you find what is null set a condition to prevent it from being null or skipping it if is null depending on what you want your code to do.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the same index (`i`) for the student and the student's grade. What you really need is a nested loop, one to iterate through the students, and an inner one to loop through that student's grades:

```
for (int i = 0; i < students.Length; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < students[i].Grades.Length; ++j)
    {
        Console.Write(" {0}: ", students[i].Grades[j].Subject);
    }
}
```

Or you can use `foreach` loops which are arguably cleaner:

```
foreach (var student in students)
{
    foreach (var grade in student.Grades)
    {
        Console.Write(" {0}: ", grade.Subject);
    }
}
```

You also need to actually create `Student` objects in your `student` array. You can't just instantiate the array itself or all of the elements will be null.

```
public Student[] students = new Student[5];  // Array of 5 null elements
for (int i = 0; i < students.Length; ++i)
    students[i] = new Student();
```

Comment: Thanks! This make it iterate through grades five times though. I only want Art, Geography and Math to be printed one time. https://i.ibb.co/ZMLjtnX/fdf.png

Comment: @Sandro You have 5 students. If each student has a grade for each of those subjects, how can you only show each subject once? What is the actual end result you're looking for? If you just want 1 student, then change the `new Student[5]` to `new Student[1]`.

Comment: Yes you're right about that. I might need to rethink this. Cause for every student I create the grades will be displayed just as many times which is wrong... Hmm.